# Appsrc seek mode in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I am using appsrc as source for my gstreamer pipeline. I have connected the "seek-data" signal  to a callback function and have done everything as mentioned in the following example code :
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/tests/examples/app/appsrc-seekable.c

However, I am not sure how do I signal seek from my code. g_signal_emit_by_name seems to be the way of doing this but its not working for me.

Please let me know if anyone knows how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an appsrc is of type `GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_SEEKABLE`, and the emit-signals property on the appsrc is `true`, the seek-event signal will be sent when a normal seek event reaches the appsrc. After connecting your callback function (seek_data in the link you provided), you can seek by calling the normal gst_element_seek(pipeline, ...) function.

See
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-eventsseek.html (seeking)
and 
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsrc.html (appsrc)